# 'class' giving compile error in header file

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-errors, header-files

I have a .h and a .cpp file and everything was working great. Once I got a huge part of the file to work right and compile I decided to create a copy of it. The copy was moved to a whole different file on my drive. I then recompiled my original file and everything went down hill.

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

class Vertebrates{
    public:
        int numberOfEyes(int x);
        int mobility(char x[]);
        int debug();            //for debugging purposes, 
}; 

#endif
```

I use geany to do my compiling. The word 'class' does not highlight any more like it used to. It is only the header file that has the issue it seems. The .cpp file compiles fine and still works.

It's just bothering me that this is not working.
I am going to attach a screen shot of the error I am getting.

[image: my error msg]

Comment: are you compiling with g++?

Comment: make clean and try again

Comment: When you copied.. did you modify the `#ifndef HEADER_H` guards?

Comment: Couple of things to look at: Look at what source file are you compiling. Go up the #includes until to get to the file where the header.h is included, check header file included *before*. Is there anything not correctly terminated? missing #endif, missing }?

Comment: Thank you all for responding so fast, I appreciate it.
I am using g++.
jsantander- I just checked, nothing was modified. I just checked the .cpp file as well and everything is fine. Everything actually still compiles. I am not sure how.

Comment: I apologize, I did not clarify. The .cpp still compiles. It is using functions from the header.h file and still runs right. The .h still does not compile.

Comment: are you compiling the *.h file?

Comment: Yes. I'm starting to think it's geany that has the problem. When I compile through terminal I do not have a problem.

Comment: I have confirmed what happened. Geany some how switched to compiling it in C and not C++. I'm probably going to stick to the terminal from now on to do the compiling. That way I know how it is compiling it. Thank you all.

Comment: You are not supposed to compile header files.